# JavaScript: Check length of URL parameter values

Tags: javascript

I've this URL here:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green
```

How can I check now with JavaScript how many values are set to the parameter separated by the comma?

So something like:

```
if (url.parameter.length > 1) {
    alert('More then 1 parameters');
} else {
    alert('Just one');
}
```

Comment: Do your values need to be comma seperated. Because there are more convenient ways

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel this is not so important. I can also be a + or /. But my whole implementation is currently based on this format so I need to change a lot of things.

Comment: `"http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green".split("?")[1].split(",").length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to get the value and then just split it by the `,`.

```js
const url = 'http://localhost.com/?color=Red,Blue,Green';

const colors = new URL(url).searchParams.get('color').split(',');
console.log(colors);
if (colors.length > 1) {
  alert('More then 1 parameters');
} else {
  alert('Just one');
}
```

Comment: This don't work in the IE browser. Is there a solution which will work?